# Which mishnah in Shas has the most daf between it and the subsequent mishnah?

Tags: talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, statistics

Beginning from:

- one  **מתני׳**  => gemara => the next **מתני׳**

**Does anyone know which mishnah has the most *dafim* between it and the subsequent mishnah?**

My gut tells me Bava Basra due to its length (176 daf) and the shortness of each *daf*, but not sure.

---

(asking as a fun fact, obviously this has no practical implication)

Comment: good question for sefaria!

Comment: In the old days, a perek of Mishnah was one Mishnah. The printed version of our Gemaras today, artificially breaks it up into smaller Mishnahs. But, the truth is, that this method is not authentic, as a full chapter is merely one long Mishnah.

Comment: @DavidKenner true, good point- asking about our modern day Bomberg Talmuds

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit: The longest section of Gemora between Mishayos in the Bomberg edition of Shas is from the first Mishna in Chelek 90a till second Mishna Chelek 107b (about 17.5 daf)

The first mishna in Sanhedrin 2a- 2b till the next Mishna in the second chapter 18a is the second longest gap (16.5 daf).

Pesachim 99b- 114b (14.5 daf)

Bava Basra 42b- 56a (14 daf)

Rosh Hashona 2a- 15b (13.5 daf)

Kiddushin 2a- 14b (12.5 daf)

Chulin 42a- 54a (12.5 daf)

Yoma 2a- 14a (<12.5 daf)

Shavuos 2b- 14a (11.5 daf)

Chullin 2a- 13a (<11.5 daf)

Yevamos 2a-13a (11 daf)

Brochos 54a- 64a (>10 daf)

Menachos 28a- 38a (>10 daf)

Note: I've only included Gemoros with over 10 Daf of Gemora between Mishnayos Thanks DonielF for input.

Comment: How do you know?

Comment: This would deserve some serious upvotes if you disclosed your methodology

Comment: @mbloch its called the check through the Shas on my shelf method and a tally chart (i'm quite old fasioned)

Comment: @joelk see my previous comment

Comment: @user15464 then it's worth an upvote :-> Not the fastest but a serious method for sure!