# What page of the Babylonian Talmud has the most words?

Tags: talmud-bavli

Looking for what page of the traditional Vilna Shas edition of the Babylonian Talmud has the most words?

Comment: Partial duplicate: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/103750/15256

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Ask me in seven and a half years

Comment: Are you asking about the longest daf or amud? (Both sides or one side?)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Berachos 32a with a whopping 864 words. If you are looking for both sides of the page, the answer is Berachos 10 with 1615 words.
I used a computer program to find it.